# C# - SQL - Function of counting a table row will only count once?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have **getRowAmount()** and **add()** function. I try to get the amount of row of a table with **getRowAmount()**. I add a value and calculate the ID or primary key based on getRowAmount + 1. So, when I add a value to the table and get the amount of row **at the first time**, it will work and ListView show rows and the amount is correct. But, when I try to add a value again (which means call the **getRowAmount()** again), It says there was a duplicate primary key. Here is my code:

```
public int getRowAmount(){

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from timelineTable", conn);
    SqlAdapter adapter = new SqlAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable virtualTable = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(virtualTable);
    int rowAmount = Convert.ToInt32(virtualTable.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    return rowAmount;
}
```

The function Above only count the row once when it is called. And I'm sorry i'm a beginner in C#. Any solution? 
Thanks!

Comment: Remove table primary key as identity and doing this is not ideal.

Comment: Why do you do that you can use `Auto_Increment` field to auto generate the next number.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know that and I did that based on my logic. Btw, thanks!

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid, that was an "awesome" advise... That is not only not ideal, that is ugly and just incorrect. Sena, dont do it like that. You will always end up with duplicates and pk violations. Look for identity in SQL Server that will take care of generating that increment values for you.

Comment: Actually I still need it because i need to print them to a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using SqlAdapter and DataTable, try using ExecuteScalar method from SqlCommand. It would be much simpler and should return the actual result from DataBase.

```
public int getRowAmount()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from timelineTable", conn);
    return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is maybe of reason of Primary_Key in your table.
to resolve this problem, I removed constraint  primary key in the table.